# Enable/Disable Internet Explorer 11 command toolbar

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

How to enable/disable this Internet explorer navbar?

[image]

On Internet Explorer 11, Windows 10 OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

How to show / hide Internet Explorer Toolbars. These commands should work on most versions of IE.

Open IE.

1. Alt-v-t-m = Menu (File, Edit, View, ...)
2. Alt-v-t-f = Favorites (Bookmarks)
3. Alt-v-t-c = Command (Home, Feeds, Mail, Print, Page, Safety, Tools, ...)
4. Alt-v-t-s = Status (Zoom, ...)

[image: Screenshot IE11 Command Toolbar toggle]

Answer (score 1):

### You can remove toolbars following these steps:

1. Click **Tools.** If you do not see Tools, press the **Alt** key to open the
   file menu and then click **Tools**.
2. In the Tools menu, click **Manage
   Add-ons**.
3. In *Manage add-ons*, under the **Toolbars and Extensions**
   section
4. Select the toolbar you want to disable and then click the
   **Disable** button.